# virtualenv virtualenvwrapper virtualenv: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-site-packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to upgrade python from 3.6 to 3.8.   I was successfully using virtualenv/wrapper successfully (although only one environment and no bells, whistles, or hooks), but the upgrade has not gone smoothly.  I deleted everything and tried to start again.   I am trying to make a new environment with `mkvirtualenv test`, and I am now getting the error:

`virtualenv: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-site-packages` after it gives a man(ual) suggestion on how to invoke `virtualenv`, which leads me to believe `virtualenvwrapper` is working, but I've missed something.

Here are my details:

terminal (osx - 10.13.6 (17G65))

```
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ which python
/usr/bin/python
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ which pip3
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ pip -V
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ pip3 -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.0.13)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: stevedore in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper) (1.32.0)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper) (5.4.4)
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ which virtualenvwrapper
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ 
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ workon
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ 
today@5 ~/dev/MST/server(master)$ mkvirtualenv test
usage: virtualenv [--version] [--with-traceback] [-v | -q] [--app-data APP_DATA] [--clear-app-data] [--discovery {builtin}] [-p py] [--creator {builtin,cpython3-posix,venv}] [--seeder {app-data,pip}] [--no-seed]
                  [--activators comma_sep_list] [--clear] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--download | --no-download] [--extra-search-dir d [d ...]] [--pip version] [--setuptools version] [--wheel version] [--no-pip]
                  [--no-setuptools] [--no-wheel] [--symlink-app-data] [--prompt prompt] [-h]
                  dest
virtualenv: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-site-packages
```

~/.bash_profile

```
#…
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
#…
```

NB -

- trying to install virtualenvwrapper it says version 4.8.4, but the online docs say it is in 5.x

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`--no-site-packages` is the default for `virtualenv` (and has been for like 5 years?) you can remove `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'` from your `.bashrc`

it appears in `virtualenv>=20` that this option was removed

Comment: I have tried that, and get the same (even after commenting out and re-sourcing bash_profile)

Comment: re-sourcing won't help since it's already in your shell's environment -- you need to open a new shell

Comment: I can read your words, but have no clue what you are saying/why it works :).   It works, but do you know where I can learn a bit more about the difference between them.   Ive never been good at lower level OS stuff :\    Thanks!

Comment: which thing would you like explained? the way sourcing works is it runs a set of commands from a file, `export X=Y` sets a global variable `X` to `Y` in your shell's environment.  nothing will unset that so re-sourcing doesn't help you

Comment: I think I get what you are saying.   I just mean that I dont know when to source vs when a new shell/screen/tab is needed.

Comment: imo never re-source rcfiles, a new session is always best (for exactly the reason you saw above ^^)

Comment: @AnthonySottile for a quick test, it's sufficient to do `unset VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS`.

Comment: Run `printenv` to see the mess. Then go to your bash profile `~/.bash_profile` (or other type) to clean up the mess. Usually it's from old env config that you forget about.